# Extracting dynamic <tr> from HTML and filling XML

Tags: c#, html, xml, html-table, html-agility-pack

I'm coding an application using C#, HTMLAGILITYPACK, HTML and XML.
That application gets all of  content  from my HTML page and with that info, create a XML archive. Example: Here's my field: https://prnt.sc/p6s958 and when I run my application, i get this: https://prnt.sc/p6saii

**There is my situation:**

I have a fieldset called by STATUS and there runs all of the events that happends, look it: https://prnt.sc/p6sc6y

There, when happend something, the HTML receives one more  and maybe after that, one more ... one more ...

I've using HTMLAGILITYPACK to get the fields by xPtah so this the structure of my Events Fieldset, and there I found a way to get the content and show up all of  content one by one using *foreach*:

```cs
foreach (HtmlNode row in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='NFe']/fieldset[5]/table/tr"))
{
     HtmlNodeCollection cells = row.SelectNodes("td");

     for (int i = 0; i < cells.Count; ++i)
     {
             if (i == 0)
                 {
                     MessageBox.Show(cells[i].InnerText); }

             else
                  {
                      MessageBox.Show(cells[i].InnerText);
                  }
      }
}
```

**How can I fill my XML with the information of my HTML Table?**

---

*There is a example when I want to extract a single field content:*

```cs
var xp_nfe_emitente = "//*[@id='NFe']/fieldset[2]"; // getting my user_info fieldset

var xp_nfe_emitente_name = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(xp_nfe_emitente + "//table/tr/td[1]/span").InnerText;

nota.NFe.infNFe.emit.name = xp_nfe_emitente_name;

/* Here, after extracted my info, I transform it on my XML (using a XMLschema)*/

XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(nfeProc));
FileStream archive= new FileStream("C:\\test\\myxml.xml", FileMode.CreateNew);
ser.Serialize(archive, note);
```

> If I wasn't clear, Let me know and I can give more information and examples (code)

Comment: Hi @DanielLima, welcome to SO. It looks like you are saving the xml already so what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Hello @JuanR thank you!! I need to extract all of <td> from my html dynamic table. It means, if i generate a XML with 5 <td> and someone add one more, when I generate my XML again, I will get 6 <td>. I did way to extract the information and show up on a MessageBox but I don't know how could I save the information and write it on my XML.

Comment: You can always write your own Xml document. This article should help: https://csharp.net-tutorials.com/xml/writing-xml-with-the-xmlwriter-class/

Comment: Yes but you see? I'm getting the fields from HTML, I know how to point a field I want to extract the content like NAME. But how can I do it with my fieldset EVENTS? There I don't have a expecific number of <td> so I can't point which field I want to fill.

Comment: How about posting a sample of the HTML?

Comment: @JuanR how could I do that? I need to save that info on my XML

Comment: Post a sample of the HTML that you are extracting from so we know what it looks like and better understand what your problem is.